# how can i convert birth date to age?

Tags: r

i have column in dataframe "fecha de nacimiento" which contains the date brith and i need to calculate the age from each one.  i've tried the following code:

```
ptje_2020 <- ptje_2020 %>%
  mutate(AGE = age_calc(FECHA_NACIMIENTO_as_date,units = "years"))
```

but it gave this error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `AGE`.
ℹ `AGE = age_calc(FECHA_NACIMIENTO_as_date, units = "years")`.
x missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Backtrace:
 1. `%>%`(...)
 8. base::.handleSimpleError(...)
 9. dplyr:::h(simpleError(msg, call))
```

how can i repair that

Comment: Where is the `age_calc` coming from?  Is it from a package, or did you write it yourself?   Post the code if it's the latter.

Comment: is from a package, could it be from eeptools, lubridate or tidiverse i install those packages for this task

Comment: @EvelynGiovanskaSilva My guess if you have some missing dates (some in the column may be `NA`). Can you share some of the data you have by doing `dput(head(ptje_2020))` and copy/paste the result into your question to make this reproducible?

Comment: For people to be able to help, we need to know what packages you're using, which means you need to know where your functions come from exactly. It's also just basic debugging practice for yourself to know what tools you're working with

Comment: @EvelynGiovanskaSilva, to find out where the function is coming from, you can type `??age_calc` to see a list of packages that you have installed that have that function.  In this case, it's from `eeptools`, like you said.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

#Try this - age from dob

```
df1$Current_age = as.numeric(difftime(Sys.Date(),FECHA_NACIMIENTO$Date_of_birth, units = "weeks"))/52.25
df1
```

Comment: This doesn't give an integer.  Usually people expect an age to be an integer.  Use `as.integer()` instead of `as.numeric()` to get an integer.

Comment: ptje2020$AGE = as.numeric(difftime(Sys.Date(),ptje_2020$FECHA_NACIMIENTO, units = "weeks"))/52.25 i tried this, but it gave me this error

Comment: Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(time2) : 'origin' must be supplied

Comment: @DDphp, I just saw that `eeptools::age_calc()` returns non-integer values.